# Problems using Class.getResourceAsStream() in Java

Tags: java

I'm a bit stuck on a project I'm working on where I want to load in a text file from another folder. I'm using Netbeans, and have, for the purposes of this problem, two folders, one with my class in, and one with the resource in.

The class is in `../misc/[ClassName]` and the text file I want to load is in `../resources/[Name].txt`

This sounds unbelievably simple, and having done Java for quite a while I really should know this, I assumed the best way of loading this file rather than using just a FileReader, would be to use `getResourceAsStream`, as shown:

```
InputStream is = 
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(_filename + ".txt");
```

Ideally saving me time and not having to hardcode in a filepath. Now, my problem is I constantly keep getting null returned from the above code, and indeed any other permutation I can put on it. I've tried `/resource/filename.txt` or `resource/filename.txt` as parameters, using `.getClass().getResourceAsStream` as opposed to `getClassLoader()`, everything is still returning the same result.

Just to avoid any confusion, I've checked the filename and its definitely right and in the right case etc. as well, so that isn't the issue. Any ideas? I know I could just use `FileReader` to accomplish the same goal, but its kind of a principle thing now!

Answer (score 13):

The class is apparently loaded by a different classloader which doesn't know about the resource at all. Rather use the context's `ClassLoader` obtained from the current `Thread` instead. It knows everything.

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(_filename + ".txt");
```

Answer (score 7):

I use IntelliJ and have found a common "gotcha" for me is forgetting to define the appropriate resource pattern to include .txt files, .css files, etc.  This means that when the build process runs it will exclude these files from the jar file it creates, causing calls to `getResource()` to return null.

I suspect a similar thing might be going on with your Netbeans environment so might be worth checking.

Comment: gosh, why don't they add .txt files by default... this saved me an hour

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem as David Meadows, 
it has worked since 2008 and no problem. Read all the post regarding `getResourceAsStream( )` here. My problem is that I can read some of the files from the jar file. All *png* file can be read, but the wav files not. The strange thing is if I rename the `.wav` file to `.png`. The files is possible to load and play!

When I deploy the application it works, could it be IntelliJ somehow ?

**Note:** I know the .wav files is there beacuse its possible to reach with JarFile and JarEntry.

**Solution in intelliJ**: In project settings, add the folder with the resource files, in my case sound files, as source. Add

> ?*.wav (or your pref filetype)

in Settings->Compiler Resource patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Where does your classpath start?  Does it start from `misc` or `..`?

Can you post the value of `this.getClass().getName()`?

If it returns `misc.ClassName` you must use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/filename.txt")`.

Comment: Yep, dropping out the `getClassLoader()` should fix it. At least, it did for me doing: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("../resources/filename.txt")`

Comment: @Ash: this makes no difference. The `cls.getResourceAsStream()` is just a shorthand for `cls.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: @BalusC: it made all the difference in a test app I wrote trying to replicate the problem. With the extra "getClassLoader()" it returned null, without it returned the stream (or URL for `getResource()`).

Comment: I had tried a zillion combination before coming across this post. The key here as @Chandru pointed out is to check the value of this.getClass().getName() & then pass the file path accordingly.